# Java unchecked conversion

Tags: java, generics, warnings

I have the following line of code

```
this.htmlSpecialChars = this.getSpecialCharMap();
```

where

```
private HashMap<String,String> htmlSpecialChars;
```

but I get a warning about an unchecked conversion. How do I stop this warning?

Comment: What type does `getSpecialCharMap()` return?

Comment: By adding `SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`?

Comment: @Joey - that's it! It was returning a HashMap not HashMap<String, String> Thanks

Comment: Please don't suppress useful warnings! / (Have you considered using `Map` as the reference type instead of `HashMap`?)

Comment: @Tom: Even then it would raise that warning if it's an unqualified generic type. The problem here were the missing type arguments on the return type of the method.

Comment: @Joey Yes. The comments divided by the / are unrelated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting this because getSpecialCharMap() is returning an object whose type cannot be verified by the compiler to be HashMap< String, String>. Go ahead and provide the prototype for getSpecialCharMap.

Answer (score 6):

You are getting the warning because the compiler cannot verify that the assignment to `htmlSpecialChars` is a HashMap<String,String>, since the method getSpecialChars() is returning a plain, non-generic HashMap.

You should modify your method to return the specific generic type:

```
private HashMap<String,String> getSpecialCharMap() {
    return new HashMap<String,String>();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way will be to modify return-type of your method to numberMap's type or this way - **please notice this is really bad practice**. Don't tell anybody that I showed you this:

**Example with unchecked conversion warning:**

```
private static HashMap getSpecialCharMap() {
    return new HashMap();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    HashMap<String,String> numberMap = getSpecialCharMap(); //warning
}
```

**Example without warning:**

```
...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    HashMap<String,String> numberMap = getSpecialCharMap();
}
```

Comment: Well, no, the *best* way would be to return the desired type: `private static HashMap<String,String> getSpecialCharMap()`

Answer (score -3):

Is the return type of `getSpecialCharMap()` non-generic HashMap? Unchecked conversion warning typically happens because of [Type Erasure in Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). In order to get around this, you need to annonate the method with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` or change the return type of `getSpecialCharMap()` to `HashMap<String, String>`.